# Javascript Array Arbitrary Index Memory Allocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, memory-management

is declaring an array and initializing some arbitrary indexes allocate all the array elements in the memory even the undefined ones?

Example:

```
var users = [];

function addUser(userID, name, address) {
   if (typeof (users[userID]) === 'undefined')
       users[userID] = new User(userID, name, address)
}

function User (userID, name, address) {
    this.userID = userID;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

$(function () {
   addUser(63, 'John', 'VA');
   addUser(5, 'Kate', 'NY');
   addUser(895, 'Yaz', 'DC');
});
```

So in the above example, will the browser allocate 896 instances of User in the memory (only 3 are defined) or only 3?

Thanks,

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, did you intend to have a close parentheses and semicolon at the end of the sample code?

Comment: Look at http://youtu.be/UJPdhx5zTaw?t=17m25s for Google Chrome.

Comment: I'm targeting all the major browsers. I fixed my jQuery syntax error

Comment: If you do `var arr = []; a[1000] = 42; console.dir(a);`, then you will see that there is only one element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nope**

JavaScript doesn't care what you put in the array, and it's not going to auto-populate it with values you didn't give it.

If you add 3 users to the array, you will only have 3 users in memory.

The indices in the gaps will just be `undefined`

---

```
var x = [];
// undefined

x[0] = "user1";
// 'user1'

x[3] = "user2";
// 'user2'

x[10] = "user3";
// 'user3'

x;
// ['user1',,,'user2',,,,,,,'user3']
```

---

All of that said, you might be better off using an `Object` (`{}`)

```
var users = {};

function addUser(userID, name, address) {
  if (!(userID in users)) {
    users[userID] = new User(userID, name, address)
  }
}
```

You will have an object that looks like this

```
{"63": [object User], "5": [object User], "895": [object User]}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the difference. Can you please elaborate more? I can see {} over there, aren't you declaring an array too?

Comment: @yazanpro, the first example uses an `Array` the second example uses an `Object`. The object won't have "gaps" like the array will. I recommend reading up on both on MDN.

Comment: Technically speaking there is no differences between arrays and objects in that case. You say that the gaps are `undefined`, but that's the same case for objects: non-existing properties are always `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling so would you suggest a better approach to achive the purpose?

Comment: @yazanpro: Since the you actually have user IDs, an object feels more appropriate. Objects are typically used as `key -> value` maps whereas arrays are more of a set of elements. And it looks like you rather want a map here.

Comment: @FelixKling, thank you for confirming my suspicion; and a very well-respected recommendation. I think the object is better in this case, too ^.^